# How can I mark all i18n changes as "fuzzy"?

Tags: internationalization, python-sphinx, gettext

I have the following scenario:

- A fellow writer is making "English only" changes to the .rst-files of a Sphinx project.
- After running `make gettext && sphinx-intl update [...] && sphinx-intl build`, some of the translations of changed msgids are marked as `fuzzy`, while others are now empty.

I am searching for a way to mark all changed translations as `fuzzy`, for example through adjusting the minimum similarity requirement for fuzzy entries.